# Connecting an html form to a sharepoint list

Tags: web-part, custom-form, form, html, content-editor-web-part

I am trying to build a customer feedback form in sharepoint. I have created a sharepoint list, which I was hoping to serve as the place where the feedback(s) will be collected. I have also made an html page for the form.

1. How do I add the html *form* to an aspx page?  ( I have tried adding the same through "Content Editor" webpart, but it doesn't seem to accept html forms. I've also seen an "html form web part" but I'm unable to add my html page so)
2. Is it possible to connect the data during a user submit to the sharepoint list without using infopath?  If yes, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Thanks a lot for those advises. Really helpful. Though I still have 2 questions: 1. How can I change the "save" button to "send" button 2. Currently, when a user clicks on the "save" button, he/she returns directly to the list. In the case of a contact form, I would like to send the user to a "thank you" page (HTML page) or to the homepage. Any ideas? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please go through https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/conduct

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/95586)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement this by creating a Custom New Form and adding the HTML you have already created to this aspx page. This will be bound to the SharePoint List .

Each SharePoint List by default has **NewForm.aspx,EditForm.aspx and a DisplayForm.aspx**. If you open the SharePoint Designer you can view them as below:

[image]

You can add a new **Custom Form** and set it as the default new form so that it will over ride the existing form for the list. 
[image]

The new form will be added along with other forms. 
[image]

Once it is created, you can add the required Controls to the aspx page and design them in different layouts

[image]

The form by default has a single column layout but that can be changed using Table formatting.
[image]

**Implementation Links**

The detailed implementation can be followed from [Here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23955.sharepoint-2013-building-custom-forms.aspx)

A detailed video on how to do the same can be found [Here](https://youtu.be/78OoeFDYSI4)

Answer (score 5):

There's a great solution which allows you to build a HTML form for SharePoint lists if you're okay using JavaScript and jQuery.

Original solution: http://www.markrackley.net/2013/08/29/easy-custom-layouts-for-default-sharepoint-forms/

Updated this year: http://www.markrackley.net/2017/05/04/customize-your-sharepoint-classic-forms-without-infopath/

Comment: Thank you so much for these pointers. I will try these out.