# Is it possible to have Angular forms connected to a SharePoint Site list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, list, angularjs

I want to know if it's possible to have HTML/Angular forms connected to a SharePoint enterprise Site list.

The client environment is Microsoft Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. We can create the Angular form using content editor webpart or hosted app.

Here is a complete reference how we can do :-)

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1002526/SharePoint-and-Angularjs

Answer (score 0):

You can connect HTML form to list by creating a Custom New Form and adding the HTML you have already created to this aspx page. This will be bound to the SharePoint List .

Each SharePoint List by default has NewForm.aspx,EditForm.aspx and a DisplayForm.aspx.
You can add a new Custom Form and set it as the default new form so that it will over ride the existing form for the list.

There's a similar situation here:

[Connecting an html form to a sharepoint list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/222619/connecting-an-html-form-to-a-sharepoint-list)